# How add custom filter to colum grid in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have custom grid in Adminhtml.

```php
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
    $collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
    $collection->addStaticField('category_id');
    $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('category_grp', 'GROUP_CONCAT(category_id)', 'category_id');

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

 $this->addColumn('category_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Category'),
        'index'     => 'category_grp',
        'type'      => 'categories',
        'options'   => $options,
        'align'     => 'left',
//      'filter_index' => $this->_getFlatExpressionColumn('category'),
    return $this;
}
```

category_grp is array with int

My question is how can i add filter to header column which filters the item from the field?

for example filter only product with category_id=7 (category_grp is 3,6,7,13)...

Comment: Actually I'm interested in learn how to create a custom filter ( if it is possible) please share info if you find anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will need any custom filter.
Just try to set `index` in accord with field name:

```
'index'     => 'category_id',
```

Comment: nnnn, if i use 'index' => 'category_id' then i have only 1 category.
Product is in multiple category... For example 3,7,13...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at magento `filter_condition_callback` option

```
$this->addColumn('categories', array(
                   ....                      
                   'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_applyMyFilter'),
                    ..
                 )
 );

 protected function _filterCategoriesCondition($collection, $column)
 {
     if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
         return;
     }

     $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('categories', array('finset' => $value));
 }
```

See

- [Filtering a text-type column with MySQL-computed values in Magento Admin Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530287/filtering-a-text-type-column-with-mysql-computed-values-in-magento-admin-grid)
- [Magento: How to search or filter by multiselect attribute in admin grid?](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-search-or-filter-by-multiselect-attribute-in-admin-grid/)