# Magento insert and filter multi-select values in custom admin-grid module

Tags: forms, magento, multi-select

I have created a custom module with Module Creator (v 1.7).
Have one multi-select admin form field.
As the multiselect field on submitting gives array , the same value (i.e Array) is stored in database.
To avoid this on saving the submitted value , I just manipulated the code by storing it in e.g a,b,c form.
Through this the data is saved successfully.
Now in grid , I want to filter it , as we have for Status part [1=>Enabled 2=>Disabled].
please suggest How would I achieve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at magento `filter_condition_callback` option

```
$this->addColumn('categories', array(
                   ....                      
                   'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_applyMyFilter'),
                    ..
                 )
 );

 protected function _filterCategoriesCondition($collection, $column)
 {
     if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
         return;
     }

     $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('categories', array('finset' => $value));
 }
```

See

- [Filtering a text-type column with MySQL-computed values in Magento Admin Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530287/filtering-a-text-type-column-with-mysql-computed-values-in-magento-admin-grid)
- [Magento: How to search or filter by multiselect attribute in admin grid?](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-search-or-filter-by-multiselect-attribute-in-admin-grid/)

Comment: Thanks @R.S . I had referred the second reference . And got success.